# php cURL how to get the return value from a file

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL to query a page and the page then does a `return` rather than an `echo` or `print` statement.

It does this because the page calls a class method which returns data, how can i grab that returned data in cURL?

i know that I can return raw information thats echoed in the file, but how about return types?

EDIT:

the page that i am calling via curl has a snippet like this

```
test.php

$test->getCall();
```

the method looks like

```
public function getCall()
{
     $str = 'test';
     return $str;
}
```

if i do

```
echo $test->getCall();
```

in a separate file

then I get test

but in the file that i am passing via cURL uses my own MVC url pattern

so i am calling `domain.com/request/getCall/`

which then executes the `getCall()` method, but unless that metho echo's something it won't work.

The `getCall()` method is used in other scripts and depends on the `return` value so i cannot change it to echo.

Comment: What do you mean "the page does a return"? Shouldn't you use `require` then?

Comment: @Czechnology - I edited to better explain my use

Comment: So why don't you do `echo $test->getCall();` in the page you're querying? I'm a bit puzzled what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What data is being returned from the return operator? cURL is expecting actual data, it has no understanding of the underlying code being run on a page it requests. You have to feed it data in some way, but if you don't want to `echo` anything you could set a header and have cURL detect the header.